# Converting dictionary to data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

First thing my loop is not working the way I want. It is giving links inside dictionary for a particular website step by step. I want to fill it at once.My output is like:

```
{'Banks – Assets': {'link': 'https://data.gov.au/dataset/banks-assets'}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimate Risk Basis': {}, 'Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of Official Reserve Assets': {}, 'Finance Companies and General Financiers – Selected Assets and Liabilities': {}, 'Liabilities and Assets – Monthly': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Immediate Risk Basis – International Claims by Country': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Ultimate Risk Basis': {}, 'Banks – Consolidated Group off-balance Sheet Business': {}, 'Liabilities of Australian-located Operations': {}, 'Building Societies – Selected Assets and Liabilities': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Immediate Risk Basis – Foreign Claims by Country': {}, 'Banks – Consolidated Group Impaired Assets': {}, 'Assets and Liabilities of Australian-Located Operations': {}, 'Managed Funds': {}, 'Daily Net Foreign Exchange Transactions': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures-Immediate Risk Basis': {}, 'Public Unit Trust': {}, 'Securitisation Vehicles': {}, 'Assets of Australian-located Operations': {}, 'Banks – Consolidated Group Capital': {}}
{'Banks – Assets': {'link': 'https://data.gov.au/dataset/banks-assets'}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimate Risk Basis': {'link': 'https://data.gov.au/dataset/consolidated-exposures-immediate-and-ultimate-risk-basis'}, 'Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of Official Reserve Assets': {}, 'Finance Companies and General Financiers – Selected Assets and Liabilities': {}, 'Liabilities and Assets – Monthly': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Immediate Risk Basis – International Claims by Country': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Ultimate Risk Basis': {}, 'Banks – Consolidated Group off-balance Sheet Business': {}, 'Liabilities of Australian-located Operations': {}, 'Building Societies – Selected Assets and Liabilities': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures – Immediate Risk Basis – Foreign Claims by Country': {}, 'Banks – Consolidated Group Impaired Assets': {}, 'Assets and Liabilities of Australian-Located Operations': {}, 'Managed Funds': {}, 'Daily Net Foreign Exchange Transactions': {}, 'Consolidated Exposures-Immediate Risk Basis': {}, 'Public Unit Trust': {}, 'Securitisation Vehicles': {}, 'Assets of Australian-located Operations': {}, 'Banks – Consolidated Group Capital': {}}
```

Second thing I want to make data frame out of it like:

```
Titles                                                  Links
Banks - Assets                      https://data.gov.au/dataset/banks-assets
Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimate Risk Basis   https://data.gov.au/dataset/consolidated-exposures-immediate-and-ultimate-risk-basis
```

and so on ...
My code is:

```
webpage4_urls = ["https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&organization=departmentofagriculturefisheriesandforestry&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=commonwealthscientificandindustrialresearchorganisation&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=bureauofmeteorology&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&organization=tasmanianmuseumandartgallery&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=department-of-industry&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&_groups_limit=0"]
for i in webpage4_urls:
    wiki2 = i
    page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    lobbying = {}
    data2 = soup.find_all('h3', class_="dataset-heading")
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}
    data2[0].a["href"]
    prefix = "https://data.gov.au"
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]
        print(lobbying)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) + [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) + [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
for element in data2:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]
    #print(lobbying)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lobbying, orient='index').rename_axis('Titles').reset_index()
    print (df)
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = []
for i in webpage4_urls:
    wiki2 = i
    page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    lobbying = {}
    data2 = soup.find_all('h3', class_="dataset-heading")
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}
    data2[0].a["href"]
    prefix = "https://data.gov.au"
    for element in data2:
        print ()
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]
        #print(lobbying)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lobbying, orient='index').rename_axis('Titles').reset_index()
        dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: I want to fit all values in csv with column names Titles and Links. I am using df.to_csv('D:/output.csv', encoding = utf-8), any other method?

Comment: Give me some second, I have to test it.

Comment: sure thing, mine is also runnig, taking alot of time.

Comment: It is possible, if a lot of data. But if use `df.to_csv('D:/output.csv', encoding = utf-8)` there is problem your data are still overwritten - write always to same file. So need for each `DataFrame` change filename.

Comment: yes this operation aborted :(. How shoul I write above data frames into one fine now?

Comment: Maybe need `df = df.drop_duplicates()` - check [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148312/discussion-between-arti123-and-jezrael).